# Java server to handle multi-clients simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, client, java-server

I am new to java server and client. I want to make a multi-client server. After making server code ready to accept more than one client it is like this :

Server code :

```
public class Server {


int clientNumber = 1;
ServerSocket mServer = new ServerSocket(9090);
try {
    while (true) {
        new TheServer(mServer.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
    }
} finally {
    mServer.close();
}
}

private static class TheServer extends Thread {
private Socket client;
private int clientNumber;

public TheServer(Socket client, int clientNumber) {
    this.client = client;
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
}

public void run() {

        try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                dos.writeUTF(numberString);

                while (true) {
                String message = br.readLine();
                dos.writeUTF(message);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

}

The clients are added to the server as I expect.

If I have one client, the --- dos.writeUTF(message); --- give the desired result inside client console, so in server console I write down (A) and press enter, then the (A) is printed inside #1 Client, then I write down (B) in server console and press enter, then the (B) is printed inside #1 Client, it seems good.

But if the second client join the server, the result inside both clients console is hold for one time press and is fired on second enter press. To simplify : Inside server console I press (A) and press enter, nothing is happening on clients consoles, then I press (B) inside server console again, and now the first message (A) and second message (B) are printed one (A) inside #1 Client and one (B) inside #2 Client and this is not the behavior that I expect.

What I expect: When 2 Clients exist and server send message (A), I need all Clients (here there are 2 clients) get the message together. Imagine you are playing a game online, If I have a character (like a ball) and I move it inside a game field, all the other players have to see my character moving. I wish I was clear.

I think I have to make an array to keep the clients and send message to that array maybe...

So how can I solve it. If the client code is needed please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into something called the Publish-Subscribe pattern, also known as the Observer pattern, here is an example:

https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java